# how to list files in a directory?

Tags: android, arrays, load, spinner

im new to android development so please forgive me if this is an easy thing to do.

i want to get all the files in a directory on the sd card and display them in a spinner, but i just cant work out how.
this is what i have and i dont even know if any of it is any good.

```
//creates this directory if its not there??     
File sd = new File("/sdcard/myfolder");

                 //gets a list of the files
                 File[] sdDirList = sd.listFiles(); 

                 //add them to the spinner array (this makes it crash)
                 for(int i=0;i<sdDirList.length;i++) 
                 array_spinnerLoad[i] = sdDirList[i].getName();
```

so where am i going wrong?
any usefull link to an easy to use tutorial anywhere?
it doesnt have to be a spinner, just some list i can select from

thank you :)

edit:
it doesnt crash with this but the spinner array is not filled

```
File[] sdDirList = sd.listFiles(); 
             if (sdDirList != null)
             {
                 array_spinnerLoad=new String[sdDirList.length];

             for(int i=0;i<sdDirList.length;i++)

             array_spinnerLoad[i] = sdDirList[i].getName();
         }
```

Comment: Small tip *(not sure if its the problem here, just in general)*: Don't hardcode paths to things like the SD-card - because these paths vary on different devices. Use [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) instead. It will return a valid path to the primary mass storage on every device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `/sdcard/myfolder` doesn't exist or is not a directory, then `listFiles` returns `null`. You're probably crashing with a NPE. You can use `exists()` and `isDirectory()` to diagnose what's wrong. (Plus, you can test that `sdDirList != null`.)

P.S. It would help you to get more accurate answers to post details about the crash -- such as the exception.

Comment: ok thanks as i said im new to this. logcat says its this line array_spinnerLoad[i] = sdDirList[i].getName(); creating a nullpointerexeption

Comment: @user1033558 - That's what would happen if `sdDirList` was `null`--you're trying to access the first element of an array that doesn't exist. (It would also happen if `sdDirList` had `null` as the first element, but `listFiles` doesn't return `null` values in the array.)

Comment: thanks ted, i have manually put files in the directory and still theres nothing there. think i need a tutorial but havnt found 1 i understand yet.

Comment: @user1033558 - Following the comment by alextsc - use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` or `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` to obtain the root path for your files. Don't use a literal string in your code. I suspect that your files are not where you think they are with respect to your program. (BTW, how did you "manually put files in the directory"?)

Comment: i put the files in the directory from my pc. i have it working now thanks. after lots of code juggling it just seemed to work, something to do with setting the adapter before the array is filled (i think lol) sorry